# Is there a way to modify Thingsboard widget bundle to add advanced filters

Tags: thingsboard, custom-widgets

**Thingsboard** CE widgets have been so helpful for timeseries data visualization, but it would be nice if there were some advanced filters based on our data, I wonder if there's a way to modify the widget code in order to add some filter, I don't know if TB API can support that. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you can make custom widget with filtered data or modify existing widget too
Every widget had onDataUpdate function you need to Modify data and datasource object before it get processed

Thanks